# how to make a command which sends an embed in a channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a private discord bot, using the library `discord.js`. I am currently using `replit.com` to edit the bot as well as to host it. I just made a new command, which is supposed to send an embed in a specific channel. I tried to make it, but when I run it, it gives this error:

```
[FATAL] Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Discord.MesageEmbed is not a constructor
      at Object.run (/home/runner/PrivateBo/Commands/Utility/welcome.js:8:17)
      at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/PrivateBot/welcome.js:107:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
      at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:66:3)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:434:9)
}  reason:  Discord.MesageEmbed is not a constructor
```

This is how my file looks like:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: "welcome",
    description: "welcomes a user",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    let embed = new Discord.MesageEmbed()
    .setAuthor("Welcome")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setDescription("Welcome member to the server! Please read <#placeholder> and chill here!")
    .setFooter("Regards, Staff Team")
  messaeg.channel.send(embed)
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on the error the problem is in typos: 
```new Discord.MesageEmbed() - Discord.MessageEmbed()```
And irrelevant but important : ```messaeg.channel.send(embed) - message.channel.send(embed)```

Comment: wdym by irrelevant?

Comment: is there a better way to mention people?

Comment: afaik no, there is no programmatic triggering in SO. 
I mean, the typo here: ```messaeg.channel.send(embed)``` is not the failure reason. yet. The main problem mentioned in the error you attached is that there is no known method `MesageEmbed`.

Answer (score 2):

Fix the typo in `new Discord.MesageEmbed()`.

Should be `Discord.MessageEmbed()`